# $e^{i\theta} = 1$ for all $\theta$?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the conceptual error in the following derivation?
$$
e^{i\theta} = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\theta} = (e^{i2\pi})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = 1^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = 1
$$
It is clear to me that the second move is illegal, I just don't know why.

Comment: I suspect that $(a^b)^c\neq a^{bc}$ in general in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I bet it's something like  (-8)^(1/3) = -2, (-8)^(1/3) != (-8)^(2/6) = 64^(1/6) = 2

Comment: I've got another head scratcher for you :

$$1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i\cdot i = i^2=-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$a^{x y} \not = (a^x)^y$ in general.

For example, $[(-1)^2]^{1/2} = 1$ but $(-1)^1 = -1$.

You may wish to look up "branch cuts" to understand conceptually why this is true.

Comment: So only if $b,c$ are integers, then $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ always?

Comment: @Joshhh Not "only if". If $a, b, c$ are all positive, for instance, then that rule holds.

Answer (score 1):

First, the formula
$$
e^{i\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\theta}=(e^{i2\pi})^{\theta/2\pi}
$$
is not correct, because $z^{\alpha\beta}=(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}$ does not hold, in general.

Second, the formula
$$
1^{\theta/2\pi}=1
$$
is not correct.

Complex power is defined as
$$
a^b = e^{b\ln a}
$$
and can have (in)finitely many values if $b$ is not a real integer.

If $z^{\alpha\beta}=(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}$ holds, then $\beta$ is an integer. For detailed information, see [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/clog_11.pdf), page 12.

Comment: But $1,\theta,2\pi$ are all real numbers.

Comment: They are not necessarily integers, except $1$. In fact, $2\pi$ is not an integer clearly.

Comment: $1^x$ is a constant function, so $1^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}$ is necessarily $1$. Why is the second move I made not true in general?

Comment: In real, your statement is true. But in complex analysis it is different. Compute $1^{1/2}$:$$1^{1/2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln 1} =e^{\frac{1}{2} 2k\pi i} = e^{k\pi i}=(-1)^k,$$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: $
{i\theta} = {i\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\theta} = \log_e (e^{i2\pi})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = \log_e 1^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = 0
$ ... at log level

Answer (score -1):

$\theta$ is the angle from the real axis so what you did that while converting $e^{i\theta}$ to $e^{i\theta \frac{2\pi}{2\pi}}$ you change the complex number because if $\theta \ne 2\pi$ then $e^{i\theta \frac{2\pi}{2\pi}} \ne e^{i2\pi \left(\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right)}$ because the argument of the $e^{i\theta }$ is $\theta$ and the argument of $e^{i2\pi}$ is $2\pi$

Comment: DeMoivre's formula [works only for integer powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers.2C_and_generalization).